# R : Finding minimum value on the basis of changing preceding and suceeding values in group by column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, reshape2

Adding for replicability:

```
  data.frame(
product=c(rep("x",2),rep("y",3)),
price_category_from=c(10,20,10,20,30),
price=c(30,31,31,30,27)
```

)

As shown below, I have a table which I would like to group by `product` and changing values of `price_category_from` column to find the minimum `price`.

```
product     price_category_from     price
  x                10                30
  x                20                31
  y                10                31
  y                20                30
  y                30                27
```

As shown below, the result table should contain minimum `price.new` column for changing the values in `price_category_from` column. For example, the `price.new` in both the rows for product `x` is `30` since the succeeding `price` value for `price_category_from` category is bigger. Whereas for product `y` the minimum value changes for every succeeding `price_category_from` categories, since next `price` values are smaller.

The values in `price_category_from` are intervals in increasing order.

```
product     price_category_from     price    price.new
  x                10                30        30
  x                20                31        30  **
  y                10                31        31
  y                20                30        30
  y                30                27        27
```

I hope that I was able to explain the problem. I would really appreciate your help (preferably with `data.table`). Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cummin` to get the cumultive minimum (minimum of all values up to the given value)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, price.new := cummin(price), by = product]

df
#    product price_category_from price price.new
# 1:       x                  10    30        30
# 2:       x                  20    31        30
# 3:       y                  10    31        31
# 4:       y                  20    30        30
# 5:       y                  30    27        27
```

Or with base R

```
df$price.new <- with(df, ave(price, product, FUN = cummin))
```

Comment: Or using `dplyr` `df %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(price.new = cummin(price))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution wit `base R` for data frame `df`

```
df.out <- Reduce(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$product), 
                              function(x) within(x,price.new <- cummin(price))))
```

such that

```
> df.out
  product price_category_from price price.new
1       x                  10    30        30
2       x                  20    31        30
3       y                  10    31        31
4       y                  20    30        30
5       y                  30    27        27
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", 
"y"), class = "factor"), price_category_from = c(10L, 20L, 10L, 
20L, 30L), price = c(30L, 31L, 31L, 30L, 27L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```